# Converting raw file into actual file in react-native

Tags: react-native, file, makefile, react-redux

I'm having an raw file getting from an server for eg:

```
file: {
fileName:xyz,
size:7125,
mimeType:document/pdf
}
```

how can i convert this to normal file and saved it to the respected directory.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have download that file and store inside your phone memory, For downloading you have following options.

1. Use that lib.

   https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#download-to-storage-directly
2. Open that link in your `browser and download it through the browser`

   https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#openurl
3. If you are using `expo` you can do in this way

   https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#example-usage